# Redirect to other page Intel XDK

Tags: javascript, html, intel-xdk

actually I'm developing on Intel XDK IDE, but I need  redirect to other page.
Thanks.

Code:

```
    $(document).on("click", "#ini-sesion", function(evt)
    {

        var user = $("#user").val();
        var pass = $("#pass").val();

        if (user == "admin" && pass == "123"){
            intel.xdk.notification.alert( user + " - " + pass, "Data", "Ok");

                  window.location.href = "#sales";
        }else{
            intel.xdk.notification.alert( "Pass & User Incorrect", "Alert!", "Ok");
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
  window.location.href = "#sales";
```

won't work, cause *href* needs an URL, not a CSS selector.

You need to have a web protocol (`http://` or `https://`), or something like this:

```
  window.location.href = "sales.html";
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
activate_subpage("#sales");
```