# How to redirect to another html page without using window.location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, intel-xdk

So, I`m working on an app in Intel XDK so if the user has no wifi connection I redirect to another page with the next script:

```
if (!navigator.onLine) {
    window.location.replace("nowifi.html");
}
```

That works fine in the web browser, but in in Intel XDK does not work because of Window location (I need to add a plugin to make it work), do you know another way to redirect?

Comment: Are you sure that `window.location` needs a plugin? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062026/redirect-to-other-page-intel-xdk) seems to work out of the box.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, since Im not using an hybrid building

Comment: I'm assuming the plugin you're referring to is the inAppBrowser plugin. Why do you not want to use that plugin? BTW - you're building a Cordova (aka PhoneGap) app when you build an app with the Intel XDK, so finding a solution for Cordova will work. Also, the behavior you get is target dependent, the XDK does not dictate the behavior of the device; Android is a particularly difficult beast regarding differences in behavior. Use the Crosswalk build to "tame" Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a hyperlink tag and simulate a click on it:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = "http://google.com";
document.body.appendChild(link).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try just location:

```
if (!navigator.onLine) {
    window.location = "nowifi.html";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it has to be without window.location, because window location doesnt work on Intel XDK